# What installer contains the Microsoft Business Intelligence Development Studio 2008?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, bids, ssrs-2008

My installation of Visual Studio Team System 2008 (Development Edition) does not have it.  I can't find it in the SQL Server Enterprise 2008 installer either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it finally.  Start the SQL server Enterprise install.  Then on about the 7th page of the install it finally comes up with a selection list where you can choose to install BIDS. Wow, now that's "great design".